# how to access mouse pointer of remote computer using socket programming?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, monitoring

I'm doing a project on client - server activity monitoring system using tcp/ip protocol, in which i have to access active time details of all client machine from server and server admin could also access mouse pointer and display of any active client machine from server.

i have been done till accessing active time details of all client computer. but i have no idea how to access mouse pointer and display of client machine from server side.

I've been using socket programming on ubuntu and for GUI GTK+3.0 programming. so, please anyone help me how to implement those things and how to program to access mouse pointer and display using socket programming using c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use frame buffering concept, concept used in VNC which allows us to see display of remote machine (generally used in Linux)

Instead of mouse pointer you can store all your system display of client machine into a frame and send it to server and render it on server similar to VNC that will allow you to get display of client.

Comment: how to implement frame buffering concept using socket programming in c, and how to store frame display? please give some details and references where i could study all those things.